# findFragmentById always returning null

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2

Initially I started creating a map to show google maps by following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) that uses a `fragment` inside a `RelativeLayout`, it worked the first couple of times, but then for some reason it's stopped working and throwing the error that `Unable to resume activity`.

This is my activity -

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    SessionManager session;
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private Location userLocation = null;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        session.checkLogin();

        try {
            // Loading map
            initializeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onStart();
    }

    public void showToast(final String toast)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initializeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();

            // ---------v  Here value of mf = null always
            MapFragment mf = (MapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = mf.getMap(); // <-- This is where the error occurs

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("Update", "Inside onResume");
        initializeMap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean authLogout(MenuItem item) {
        session.logoutUser();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

And `fragment_map.xml` file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Eclipse also created a file called `activity_map.xml` when generating the blank activity -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lokay2.MapActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

The Logcat -

```
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.lokay2/com.example.lokay2.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at com.example.lokay2.MapActivity.initializeMap(MapActivity.java:60)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at com.example.lokay2.MapActivity.onResume(MapActivity.java:75)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2860)
03-23 15:29:34.353: E/AndroidRuntime(8432):     ... 12 more
```

I've went through a *lot* of questions with the same problem. Most of them suggested using SupportMapFragment. But from [MapFragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html) -

> Use this class only if you are targeting API 12 and above. Otherwise, use SupportMapFragment.

And in most of the problems, the cause was different than others. So kindly give it a thought if you're going to flag it as duplicate.

I'm targeting API 17. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MapActivity has no layout, so that why it cannot find fragment with that ID. Call `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map)` within your `onCreate()` method. Also rename fragment_map layout to activity_map which make more sense since you are using it for activity.

Comment: There's already an `activity_map` file. Eclipse created both that and the `fragment_map` files. You can see the activity_map here http://paste.ubuntu.com/7140231/

Comment: I see you want to create MapFragment within PlaceHolderFragment but this fragment isn't attached to main activity. Drop it and use only MapFragment.

Comment: You mean remove `PlaceholderFragment` class and call setContentView from the activity's onCreate?

Comment: Yes. Because now you have activity which has no layout...ok, generated from eclipse but doesn't contain any fragment. Than inner class for Fragment which is not used at all. Remove 'PlaceholderFragment' and do it as I wrote in answer

Comment: Phew! I thought something weird was going on when I had a file called fragment_map and it was never used in any of the code. But couldn't find a right reference. Thanks a bunch.